# Python: Counting Zeros in multiple array columns and store them efficently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, counting

I create an array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = [[0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
arr = np.array(arr)
```

Now I count every zero per column and store it in a variable:

```
a = np.count_nonzero(arr[:,0]==0)
b = np.count_nonzero(arr[:,1]==0)
c = np.count_nonzero(arr[:,2]==0)
```

This code works fine. But in my case I have many more columns with over 70000 values in each. This would be many more lines of code and a very messy variable expolorer in spyder.

My questions:

1. Is there a possibility to make this code more efficient and save the values only in one type of data, e.g. a dictionary, dataframe or tuple?
2. Can I use a loop for creating the dic, dataframe or tuple?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a boolean array `arr == 0` and then take its sum along the rows.

```
>>> (arr == 0).sum(0)
array([3, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ordered dict from the collections module:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint as pp
import string

arr = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
letters = string.ascii_letters
od = OrderedDict()

for i in range(len(arr)):
    od[letters[i]] = np.count_nonzero(arr[:, i]==0)

pp(od)
```

Returning:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)])
```

Example usage:

```
print(f"First number of zeros: {od.get('a')}")
```

Will give you:

```
First number of zeros: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To count zeros you can count non-zeros along each column and subtract result from length of each column:

```
arr.shape[0] - np.count_nonzero(arr, axis=0)
```

produces `[3,1,1]`.

This solution is very fast because no extra large objects are created.